# java matcher doesn't process ^ and $ symbols

Tags: java, regex

There is email pattern:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.]*[a-zA-Z]$`

and the example code, that try to get email from string:

```
String email = "NAME <firstname_lastname@domain.com>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

When regexp contains `^` and `$` characters, `matcher.find()` returns false, but when regexp is without these characters, all is fine: I see `firstname_lastname@domain.com` in console.

Could you please explain difference between regexp with and without `^` and `$`?

How can I force the Matcher to work with regexp that contains `^` and `$`?

Comment: Please google "regex anchor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^ & $` matches beginning and end of String (either Line or Full text if MultiLine switch is turned on). You can trim them from the pattern if you need to extract email from a text.

```
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[a-zA-Z0-9][\\w.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\\w.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.]*[a-zA-Z]$";
    String email = "NAME <firstname_lastname@domain.com>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN.substring(1, EMAIL_PATTERN.length()-1));
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

**Output**

```
firstname_lastname@domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` and `$` mean begin and end of the input, respectively. The `"NAME <...>"` surrounding the address causes the `Matcher` to ignore the potential match it could find it it wasn't for the `^` and `$`.

Comment: okay, thank you! is there the opportunity in Matcher or in Pattern classes to ignore these anchors?

Comment: @hard-code Of course. Remove them from the pattern and the Matcher will ignore them.

Comment: No they don't. They mean start and end **of string** (or before a linebreak at the end of string), respectively. They only mean beginning/end of **line** if the `MULTILINE`/`(?m)` flag is set. See [`Pattern MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) (This is true in most regex flavors, with Ruby being an exception.)